# Creating custom HTML templates with user input

Tags: html, templates, input

I'm currently working on a project where the user needs to fill in a form which will be converted into HTML.

For example the user fills in the next form:

```
    <form method="POST" action="">
      Edit title: <input type="text" name="title"><br />
      Edit subtitle: <input type="text" name="subtitle"><br />
      Edit image: <input type="file" />
      <input type="submit" value="OK" />
    </form>
```

And the output has got to be in HTML, something like this:

```
    <div class='container'>
      <div class='leftBLock'>
       <h2>*Title*</h2>
       <p>*Subtitle*</p>
       <img src='path/to/img/image.jpg' />       
      </div>
    </div>
```

Do you guys know a way to easily get this done?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I forgot to mention that I prefer a client-side solution.

Comment: you can store them in a db table with fields like tag_name, tag_value, parent_id, when displaying iterate through sql result and print.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to do is..

Store data in Table MySQL and fetch data in php file

```
<?php
    //connection to database
    //database query
?>
<div class='container'>
      <div class='leftBLock'>
       <h2><?php echo $rs['title']; ?></h2>
       <p><?php echo $rs['subtitle']; ?></p>
       <img src='<?php echo $rs['image']; ?>' />       
      </div>
    </div>
```